# How to make the featured image just show up on the blog page?

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am trying to display a featured image but only just as a thumbnail to my blog post, however, every time I add a featured image it also shows in my blog post above the headline and I don't want that.

Is there any way to fix this, some sort of plugin to help? I am not used to editing CSS so if that's what it takes can you please give me step by step instruction or at least point me to a source which goes into it thoroughly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: for desired featured image display, you have to go your index.php file. And then make some change in HTML and CSS side. If dont' want to change in your theme. Then, you can make child theme. It will not affect your current theme. You can your child theme plugin. But you have to changes in HTML and CSS as you want.

Comment: I have a child theme. Do you know what I will need to change?

Comment: If you want featured image on blog listing page, then make index.php file in your child theme. Then copy all the code of parents theme's index.php file to your child theme and then change the html code of featured image. If you get stuck then send me code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Having a Child Theme is a good start; if you were to make changes to the main theme, those changes would get overwritten on a theme update.

In order to solve your problem, you will need to change how the various templates work. And in order to determine which template to use, you need to understand the WordPress Template Hierarchy, explained here in the Codex https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ .

Based on that information, and the files in your theme, you would need to copy the appropriate template file from the theme folder and place it in your Child Theme folder. Then edit that file (in the Child Theme folder) to make the changes on how different elements of the page are 'built' by WP using the template.

Specifics depend on the actual theme code (which varies from theme to theme). But, with a bit of PHP knowledge, you should be able to figure out what pieces of the code to change to not display the featured image wherever the theme puts it.

Because your new template is in your Child Theme folder, that template is used instead of the one in your parent theme. So changes you make will be used.